# massive.connectSync not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, massivejs

Why do I get this error, massive.connectSync is not a function when I run server.js. It works on my mac, but not my windows. Please help solve this `enter code here`error

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var massive = require("massive");
var connectionString = "postgres://massive:@localhost/MarketSpace";

// connect to Massive and get the db instance. You can safely use the
// convenience sync method here because its on app load
// you can also use loadSync - it's an alias
var massiveInstance = massive.connectSync({connectionString : connectionString})

// Set a reference to the massive instance on Express' app:
app.set('db', massiveInstance);
http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 4):

Synchronous functions are no longer supported, and the connect function itself no longer exists, it's all promises all the way:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var massive = require("massive");
var connectionString = "postgres://massive:@localhost/MarketSpace";

massive(connectionString).then(massiveInstance => {
    app.set('db', massiveInstance);
    http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
});
```

Note that massive requires node > 6. If you are using and older version you'll need to update node in order to use massive.

[Docs](https://dmfay.github.io/massive-js/connecting.html)

Comment: What version of Massive and Node are you using?

Comment: massive = ^3.1.0; node: v8.1.4